# Make GRUB automatically boot Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub

I am running a dual-boot with Ubuntu (10.10) and Windows 7. Recently I edited my /boot/grub/grub.cfg file to only show one version of Ubuntu (as opposed to several kernel versions) and Windows, simply by commenting out all other menu entries. My question is if I can edit GRUB to just boot a specific entry automatically.

I tried removing all other menu entries, but GRUB still showed the menu with only one entry. I've also considered just setting the timeout to either 0 or 1 second, as this would basically achieve the same thing.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to modify your grub2 settings in Ubuntu is by editing `/etc/default/grub` and then running `update-grub` (the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is not meant to be edited). You can find more information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2).

Using [Ubuntu Startup Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StartUpManager) can be of use if you prefer a GUI to do the changes.

Comment: StartUp-Manager is obsolete, its development stopped <2011. StartUp-Manager is incompatible with Ubuntu 11.10 and newer

Answer (score 1):

The [Ubuntu StartUp Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StartUpManager) should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could add following line to menu.lst:

```
 hiddenmenu
```

this will hide the menu, and then maybe set timeout to 0 or 1 (I don't know how timeout=0 behaves exactly).

edit: oh yes, and set line

```
default=##
```

where ## is the menuitem number starting from 0